# C# математические действия с float

Tags: c#, float

Ошибка  CS0266  Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "float" в "int". Существует явное преобразование (возможно, пропущено приведение типов

https://pastebin.com/gaR9Rj14

Comment: -1 - Ошибка в другой строке кода.

Comment: Могу залить на pastebin

Comment: Ну давай. Только в вопрос ссылку добавь, а пример свой удали.

Comment: @D.Stark Не надо удалять код из вопроса. Наоборот - надо добавлять код в вопрос.

Comment: обновил  чекайте

Comment: @Николай в вопрос добавь полный текст программы. Ссылка может слететь и вопрос потеряет свою информативность.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static int Calculate(string action1, float a2, float a1)
{
  ...
}
```

Результат вычислений с операндами `float` (то есть тип результата тоже `float`) не может быть неявно приведен к типу возвращаемому функцией - `int`. Надо:

```
public static float Calculate(string action1, float a2, float a1)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: ох, как я сам не додумался, спасибо хд просто раньше чисто int было